# Difference of Entropy of two-dimensional Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, polar-coordinates, information-theory, entropy

I encountered a putative contradiction. Assume we have two 2-dim. Gaussian variables $z_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ with all components being independent, normal distributed variables: $x_1,y_1= N(0,\sigma_1)$ and $x_2,y_2= N(0,\sigma_2)$.

Now, I want to calculate the difference of the entropies of the vectors $D=H_1-H_2$. Considering independent Gaussian variables the entropies of the components, $H_{x,y} = \frac{1}{2}\log(2\sigma^2\pi e)$, simply add up and I get $H_1 = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\log(2\sigma_1^2\pi e)$ and $H_1 = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\log(2\sigma_2^2\pi e)$. Therefore, $D = 2\log(\sigma_1/\sigma_2)$.

On the other hand, decomposing the vectors in polar coordinates (length $r$ and phase $\phi$, again independent) one finds that $r$ follows a Rayleigh distribution and $\phi$ a uniform distribution. Hence, $H_r = \frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2e^{2+\Gamma})$ and $H_\phi = \log(2\pi)$. Now, the difference of the entropies is $D=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2e^{2+\Gamma})-\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2e^{2+\Gamma})+\log(2\pi)-\log(2\pi) = \log(\sigma_1/\sigma_2)$.

Can anyone tell me how the difference of a factor 2 comes about?

The difference of the entropies corresponds to a mutual information (in my special case) and should be independent of the coordinate system. Anyway, the difference of entropies should be invariant under the chosen basis.

(The entropies of Normal, Uniform and Rayleigh distributions I got from wiki.)

Comment: When you write $x_1=y_1=N(0,σ_1)$ you mean that the components are identically distributed, not that they are equal, no? I so, that's bad notation.

Comment: you are right, thanks! edited accordingly.

Comment: "The difference of the entropies corresponds to a mutual information " Why?

Comment: this is of course not generally the case. however, in my case (research project) the entropies $H_1, H_2$ correspond to some entropies $H(X)$ and $H(X|Y)$, respectively.